# Add div on query loop page change

Tags: javascript

I have a little bit of JS that is wrapping elements of a blog module in a div in order to be able to create a flexbox layout

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".et_pb_post").each(function() {
        $(this).find(".entry-title, .post-meta, .post-content ").wrapAll('<div class="pa-blog-text"></div>');
    });

});
```

At the moment this is firing on document.ready so it only works for the initial page load. If you press the 'older entries' button on a list of posts the newly returned posts do not get the class and the flexbox layout is broken.

Can anyone suggest how I should fire this snippet so that it adds the class to the newly returned posts when pagination is used?

Comment: Assuming the 'older entries' are retrieved with an ajax call the way to go would be to bind this to the ajaxcomplete event: https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

Comment: In order to eliminate the problem, inkluding the cause, I'd try to add that div in the loop output with a WordPress Hook (in PHP), rather that adding it dynamically after it is being rendered. That makes your layout work on every page render without worrying about Javascript working or not.